# NuSOAP PHP web service and .NET WebService reference - problem

Tags: php, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have created a PHP SOAP WebService with NuSOAP. I add a WebReference from C# application. I enter the URL of the WSDL, I can see methods in the wizard but no proxy code is generated. When I do update web reference, I get error message box:

`The custom tool 'MSDiscoCodeGenerator' failed. Unable to import binding 'XXXSoapBinding' from namespace 'URL of my namespace'`

Any hints are warmly welcome.

Regards

Dominik

Comment: The binding section of your WSDL will help... please paste.

Comment: I've enclosed the binding section below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the binding section of my WSDL:

```
<binding name="MyAppMobileWebServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:MyAppMobileWebServiceSoapPortType">
  <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <operation name="Login">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php/Login" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="Logout">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php/Logout" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="GetPaletStatus">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php/GetPaletStatus" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="GetPaletsInfo">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php/GetPaletsInfo" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="GetParcelDeliveryPaletsStatus">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php/GetParcelDeliveryPaletsStatus" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="GetParcelReceptionPaletsStatus">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php/GetParcelReceptionPaletsStatus" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="GetParcelReloadPaletsStatus">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php/GetParcelReloadPaletsStatus" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="GetPaletCategories">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php/GetPaletCategories" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="GetPaletHeights">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php/GetPaletHeights" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="GetPaletTypes">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php/GetPaletTypes" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="GetPaletWeights">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php/GetPaletWeights" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="GetUsers">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php/GetUsers" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="GetDepartmentList">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php/GetDepartmentList" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
</binding>
<service name="MyAppMobileWebServiceSoap">
  <port name="MyAppMobileWebServiceSoapPort" binding="tns:MyAppMobileWebServiceSoapBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://mobile.mydomain.pl/index.php"/>
  </port>
</service>
```